# Changing HTML5 Canvas text span color

Tags: html, text, colors, canvas

Is there a way to change the color of a span of text without having to start a new fillText?

The downside to starting a new fillText is that presumably I'll have to somehow calculate the position where the first ended to try to join the next bit of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to change the color without starting a new fillText in the current spec.